# How to specify an anchor for material-ui card title?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple Card in material-ui:

```
 <Card>
    <CardHeader
      title={this.props.series.name} />
  </Card>
```

And I would like to have the title be a link to a URL that I pass in via a property. I looked at the JSX source for the card header, but I cannot figure out how to make this happen.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is to just put an `a` tag inside the title attribute of CardHeader:

```
<CardHeader
    action={
        <IconButton>
            <MoreVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
    }
    title={
        <Link to={url}>{props.name}</Link> //similarly use `a` if not using react-router
    }
    // For making an avatar link
    avatar={
        <Avatar component={Link} to={url} aria-label={props.name} className={classes.avatar}>
            A
        </Avatar>
            }
    subheader={props.subheader}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <CardHeader
    avatar={
      <Avatar aria-label={placeData.type} className={classes.avatar}>
        <PlaceTypeIcon type={placeData.type} />
      </Avatar>
    }
    action={
      <IconButton href={gMapUrl} aria-label="maps">
        <MapOutlinedIcon />
      </IconButton>
    }
    title={placeData.title}
    subheader={placeData.street}
  />
```

putting it in the action prop also works fine

Answer (score 0):

There seems no provision to make header as `<a>` from [sourcecode](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/card/card-header.jsx#L115).

But there are some hacks which you can use to get things working

1. pass `<a href=''>` as value to that prop
2. listen to click event and fire transitionTo to change the route.

Answer (score 0):

This here worked for me, I just put a Material UI Link inside of the `CardHeader subheader`.

```
<CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label={placeData.type} className={classes.avatar}>
            <PlaceTypeIcon type={placeData.type} />
          </Avatar>
        }
        title={placeData.title}
        subheader={
          <Link className={classes.link} href={gMapUrl}>
            {placeData.street}
          </Link>
        }
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

If making it an `<a href={} />` does not work, I am sure this will:

```
    <Card>
      <CardHeader title={this.props.series.name} onClick={this.props.series.link} style={linkStyle}/>
    </Card>
```

And assign a custom `linkStyle` that would make the `<CardHeader/>` look like a link.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me.

```
  <CardTitle title={renderHTML('<a href="YOUR-LINK">TITLE</a>' )}/>
```

You can use same method for subtitle as well.

Comment: this is not a solution, seems too hacky